# why i always missing mysqlid.sockfile?

Tags: 12.04

I repeatedly missed `mysqlid.sock` file in ubuntu how can i generate this missed file
, why this file always missing in ubuntu?

the error is can't connect through `var/run/mysql/mysqlid.sock (2)`

Because of this my software is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqld.sock` isn't a regular file, but a socket used to connect to a running mysql instance. Because of Linux' *Everything is a file* philosophy, it presents like a file to te user.

A missing socket usually indicates that either the program creating that socket – mySQL or mariaDB in your case – isn't running (properly) or the program is not configured to create that socket.

You can check if mysql is running by issuing `service mysqld status`.

To check whether mysql is configured to create the socket you are looking for, open `/etc/my.cnf` with a text editor of your choice and look for a line like the following. It should be in the `mysqld` section of the file.

```
socket=/var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock
```